# SharePoint Online Questions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-on-prem

I have SharePoint Online, If somebody can help to answer it.

1. Can we make SharePoint Online as public facing website ?
2. SharePoint Online can supports multilingual website ? Can we make site variation ?
3. We have already **on premise SharePoint 2013 intranet website** and due to security reason we don't want to make that SharePoint  as Public website. We want to make same website on **SharePoint Online**. So now my question is that, can we sync on **Premise SharePoint 2013 with SharePoint Online.**

Hope I will get some expert reply on this.

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions in the same post. It makes it difficult for a single user to give you a complete answer, and hence difficult for you to accept a single one of the answers you recieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The Public Website in SharePoint Online – [which is part of Office 365](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/websites-in-sharepoint-online-and-sharepoint-server-HA102828142.aspx)
2. SharePoint online Support multi-language, [check this link for all supported languages](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff463597%28v=office.15%29.aspx), Variations is not available for Office 365 public websites But if you have SharePoint online plan(Plan1 or Plan2), then you have it but not sure about public sites. [check this](http://the-north.com/sharepoint/post/Variations-available-in-Office-365-but-not-for-Public-Websites)
3. Their is no OOTB way to sync the On prem to SharePoint Online. But couple of things you can do.

   - Manually copy the data from On prem to SPO (depending upon the
     data). may be using the windows explorer but you will lose the meta data.
   - Hybrid Farm(very expensive)
   - Write your own application /Code to move the content from On prem to online.
   - use 3rd party tool to move the data. i.e sharegate, metalogix.

Answer (score 1):

When you subscribe as a tenant to Microsoft SharePoint online you are given the option to have 1 public facing website (internet site) at no additional cost that counts up against your total size allocated and it is managed pretty much like any other site collection.

When you create a site (even a public facing one) you have a choice of selecting the language of the template among any language. I do not believe you can change that later.

I don't think your point 3 is achievable out of the box, you might have to create a custom event for that. Consider SharePoint online depending on the license you will buy has some limitations in terms of 'connections' from outside so it might be that you can create an event that 'sends' data FROM sharepoint on premise, but it is not said that SharePoint online is able to 'receive' it.